# How to Install Sharepoint Online Management Shell on Powershell 5?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, powershell

I need to migrate 300K records from my filesystem to Sharepoint Online (SPO).
I am on Win7 SP1 and have MS System Center 2012 Configuration Mgr. installed so can't install WMF/Powershell 3 or 4, but have installed WMF/Powershell 5. I try to install SPO Management Shell and it requires Powershell 3.

How can SPO Management Shell be installed on Powershell 5?

Any other way to get the SPO Migration cmdlets intio my PS ISE?

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple way to achieve that except powershell,
Either you can achieve that using **Open with Explorer** or **Drag and DROP** (100 files at the same time) .

you can check below link for details:

http://sharepointmaven.com/4-ways-to-migrate-documents-to-sharepoint

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Upload-files-to-a-library-da549fb1-1fcb-4167-87d0-4693e93cb7a0?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Answer (score 0):

Install the SharePoint Online Management Shell by downloading and running the SharePoint Online Management Shell or installing the module from the PowerShell Gallery.

Once installed, the module is available for use, and you do not need to install it again until you need features introduced in a later version.